# Is there any systems-management tool for Raspberry Pi OS, like Red-Hat Satellite for Red-hat?

Tags: software-compatibility, repository

I am looking system management tool for Raspberry PI OS.

As i am maintaining more than 40+ Raspberry Pi OS. So its very difficult to apply same version of security patch and monitor all the device from single system.

So i am looking tool, that can support below requirements.

- System management solution that enables you to deploy, configure, and maintain Raspberry pi OS.
- Also provides provisioning, remote management and monitoring of multiple Raspberry/Raspbian with a single, centralized tool.
- Centralize tool can help us to install and update kernel/Os/packages to all Raspberry Client system.
- Managed Raspberry/Raspbian repository locally, as internet access can be quite restrictive.

**Please let me know if you know some tools can support the above requirement for Raspberry pi.**
**strong text**

Thanks,

Bhavik Gajera